# Why doesn't acid dissociation always have K>1?

Tags: acid-base, free-energy

Acid dissociation is usually exothermic, and it has an increase in entropy, so the change in Gibbs free energy should be negative. So why isn't always  $K_\mathrm{a}>1$ in accordance with $\Delta G^\circ = -RT\ln K$? For example, when $\ce{H3PO4}$ dissolves, the change in enthalpy is $\pu{-14.2 kJ/mol}$, and the entropy presumably increases, but $K_\mathrm{a} = \pu{7.6E-3}$ (less than 1).

Edit: Apparently acid dissociation doesn't usually increase entropy, so my new question is why that is.

Comment: Dissolution and dissociation are different processes. Most of dissolved  H3PO4 is not dissociated

Comment: Right, I was trying to talk about dissociation. Edited.

Comment: "Acid dissociation is usually exothermic" reference to support this assertion, please

Comment: Well in this case it is exothermic

Comment: 7/8 in the table here: https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Inorganic_Chemistry_(LibreTexts)/06%3A_Acid-Base_and_Donor-Acceptor_Chemistry/6.03%3A_Brnsted-Lowry_Concept/6.3.05%3A_Thermodynamics_of_Solution-Phase_Brnsted_Acidity_and_Basicity

Comment: It seems that the reason is that dissociation of H3PO4 doesn't actually increase entropy. But why?

Comment: Dissociation is exothermic only if ion hydration is more exothermic than the heterolytic breaking of R-H bond is endothermic.

Comment: Note: it's ΔG$^∘$=-RTln(K) *not* ΔG=-RTln(K).

Comment: Solvated ions have a fairly structured shell of water molecules around them which have lower entropy than bulk water. The number of water molecules involved and strength of structure will vary with ion.